# How can I open the chest in 1-8 of Chrome version?

Tags: angry-birds

I have tried other instructions I found, like clicking and typing "OPEN", but nothing seems to work.

How can I unlock the chest?

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be tagged "angry-birds-chrome" or "angry-birds" and chrome. In the meantime, I've done the latter.

Comment: If all else fails, try bashing your forehead repeatedly into your keyboard.  This solves most of my problems in a variety of cases.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/what-to-retag-chrome-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't open the chest at all in the chrome version: you have to use your birds to hit randomly placed chrome balls, in some levels. The first one is in level 1-16, and you need to zoom out all the way to see it, on this little floating island. Also in level 1-18, zoom out to find that at the top of the mound there is a chrome ball.

Answer (score 2):

You can't open the chest. Unlike in the Touch version it doesn't give anything but 500 points when you destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Just tried, doesn't work.  I am thinking the Chrome version doesn't actually have the Golden Eggs, instead it has the Chrome Dimension levels.

---

Try clicking repeatedly on/around it.  I couldn't get the chest to open right away in the Android version either, I had to mess around for a bit.  Maybe try throwing a bird first too.